# Values in an array not passing from ViewDidLoad to ViewWIllAppear

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode

I am running a function in `ViewDidLoad` that fetches a String Array from Firebase (containing a list of 'autoIds'), I then append this retrieved array to a variable, initialised in the Vc. I want to use the count of this array in another function that operates in `ViewWillAppear`, but the variable.count does not show in `ViewDidLoad` or `ViewWillAppear`, despite it successfully retrieving the data, and appending it to the variable. I've spent the best part of two days researching and investigating - I'm sure I can't find an answer as it's so obvious!!! Here's my code:

```
var totalPosts = [String]
```

The function that I call in `ViewDidLoad` is as follows:-

```
func calcTotalPosts() {
    let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    let ref = DB_BASE.child("user-posts").child(uid!)

    ref.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
        let postId = snapshot.key
        self.totalPosts.append(postId)
        print(self.totalPosts)
    }
}
```

I know the Firebase retrieve works as when I print I can see all the correct autoIds, but when I check this in `ViewWIllAppear` using the same print statement, the array is empty.

Any help - much appreciated!!

Comment: Your observe is asynchronous. It means that self.totalPosts.append will happen maybe after viewWillAppear

Comment: Make sure that you accept answers that are correct. Or leave a comment if it is not correct. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that you are having is that your request to Firebase is asynchronous and may take some time to complete.

In that time your `viewWillAppear` function has already run.

The order is like this...

1. viewDidLoad
2. Start firebase request
3. viewWillAppear runs
4. Firebase request completes and your array is populated.

If you want to use the values in your array to populate the view then you will need to respond to the array being updated.

I suggest using a `didSet` on the array...

```
// this is a property on the class (like it is already) but with a didSet on it
var totalPosts: [String] = [] {
    didSet {
        // this is a new function that updates the view based on the values in the array
        // e.g. this might populate a label or update a table view
        updateViewWithNewArrayValues()
    }
}
```

Now you can create this function and it will be called each time the array changes. And won’t depend on going if how long the Firebase request takes.

Your fetch function will remain the same. But now in the line... `self.totalPosts.append(postId)` it will now trigger the `didSet` to run on the array and cause the view to update.

You no longer have to rely on the timing of the function completing. Any updates to the array will trigger the view to be updated.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @Fogmeister - just trying to get it to work. Should the didSet variables go in ViewDidLoad or ViewWIllAppear? And where you have 'updateViewWithNewArrayValues()', is this the Firebase retrieve?

Comment: No, the array should be a property of the class. The “updateView” function should be used to take the values from the array and update your view. Still use your fetch method without changing it.

Comment: @PlanB I updated the answer a bit to add some clarifications.